# How to save the for loop output as data.frame in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, save

I'd like to know how I can save the output of a `for loop` as `data.frame`? 
let's say using the `mtcars` dataset I have  the following `for loop` script:

```
for (i in seq_len(nrow(mtcars))) { 
  if (i  <= 30) {

    next
  }

  print(mtcars[i,])  
}

              mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb
Maserati Bora  15   8  301 335 3.54 3.57 14.6  0  1    5    8
            mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb
Volvo 142E 21.4   4  121 109 4.11 2.78 18.6  1  1    4    2
```

but if I am going to `save` it in `output` file as `dataframe`  I will get the following:

```
   output <- as.data.frame(c())
    for (i in seq_len(nrow(mtcars))) { 
      if (i  <= 30) {

        next
      }

      output<- c(output,mtcars[i,])  
    }


   ### then the output is 

   > output
    $mpg
    [1] 15

    $cyl
    [1] 8

    $disp
    [1] 301

    $hp
    [1] 335

    $drat
    [1] 3.54

    $wt
    [1] 3.57

    $qsec
    [1] 14.6

    $vs
    [1] 0

    $am
    [1] 1

    $gear
    [1] 5

    $carb
    [1] 8

    $mpg
    [1] 21.4

    $cyl
    [1] 4

    $disp
    [1] 121

    $hp
    [1] 109

    $drat
    [1] 4.11

    $wt
    [1] 2.78

    $qsec
    [1] 18.6

    $vs
    [1] 1

    $am
    [1] 1

    $gear
    [1] 4

    $carb
    [1] 2
```

I know the simple indexing `output <- mtcars[-(1:30), ]`, but this is not a solution for my real life situation (which is more complex). I really need the loop to do what I want.

Comment: By using c() you're concatenating a list of data.frames. By using cbind() instead of c() you'd get what you want

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper , would you please write your code for me to clarify exactly what you  mean and where  need to do it? tnx

Comment: @jogo , tnx for the comment but it is not helpful ! I knew this , the point is to how do it in loop and this is just as example buddy! :)

Comment: output <- as.data.frame(c())
    for (i in seq_len(nrow(mtcars))) { 
      if (i  <= 30) {

        next
      }

      output<- cbind(output,mtcars[i,])  
    }

Comment: It returns an error (I hadn't tested), but use rbind() instead of cbind() and it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution that is most similar to your code.
The points are using the initialisation (indexing `...[NULL, ]`) and the function `rbind()`

```
output <- mtcars[NULL,]
for (i in seq_len(nrow(mtcars))) { 
  if (i  <= 30) {
        next
  }
  # ...
  output <- rbind(output, mtcars[i, ]) 
}
```