# Append data to data frame in a loops, but only the last value made it into the data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, while-loop, output

I have a `for loop,& while loop` which produces a data after each iteration.
I want to add all the data together in a data frame but find it difficult. Because only the last data created from the loop is successful(can be seen in the following picture:[output code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOnuE.png)).

Here is the code, please suggest how to fix it:

```
df = data.frame(matrix(nrow = 350, ncol = 12))
kol<-1
    for (x in 1:350) {
      output  <-  c(paste0(x))
      df[,1] = output 
    }
      while (kol <= 223) {
          if(kol < 224){
            rowd1 <- c(paste("gen ",kol))
          }
          df[,2] = rowd1
          kol = kol+1
        }#while

      while (kol <= 446) {
          if(kol < 447){
            rowd2 <- c(paste("gen ",kol))
          }
        df[,3] = rowd2
          kol = kol+1
      } 
colnames(df) <- c("Kromosom", "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K")    
df
```

so, I will update the question I posed.
what if the code becomes like this:
the problem: [row problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMIvA.png)

```
 ... 
    for (x in 1:350) {
            output  <-  c(paste0(x))
            df[x,1] = output
          }
    for (x2 in 1:223) {
            output2  <-  c(paste("Gen ",x2))
            df[1,2:224] = output2
          }"#why only the value 223 comes out, like the output in the picture 'row problem' that is -Gen 223-"
  ...
```

Comment: welcome to SO. this question has been answered many times - for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42419518/how-to-save-the-for-loop-output-as-data-frame-in-r

Comment: Thank you for your attention to this matter

Comment: I would probably stay away from `while` here. Why not just use `for`  instead?

Comment: roger that, I'm just trying it!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save the for loop output as data.frame in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42419518/how-to-save-the-for-loop-output-as-data-frame-in-r)

Comment: actually, it helps but the specifications are closer to the answer that Mr. @JamesHirschorn has

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **SOLVED**

*Special thanks to  @JamesHirschorn*, I really appreciate your help in resolving the problem. And thanks to the people who give feedback.

#### To Do

- would probably stay away from `while` here. Why not just use for
  instead? –  GuedesBF
- use `df[x, 1] = output` to set the value for each row in the 1st column

#### Code

```
 df = data.frame(matrix(nrow = 350, ncol = 224))
    for (x in 1:350) {
     output  <-  c(paste(x))
     df[x,1] = output
 }
    for (x2 in 2:224) {
     output2  <-  c(paste("Gen ",x2-1))
     df[1,x2] = output2
  }
colnames(df) <- c("Kromosom", "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K", ...)    
df
```

**Output**: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AR6ee.png)
.So, wish me luck in the future

Answer (score 0):

For a `data.frame` `df`, `df[,n]` is the entire n-th column. So you are setting the entire column at each step. In your code, use

```
df[x, 1] = output
```

for example, to set the value for a single row.

Comment: I have tried Mr. @GuedesBF suggestion, and according to your words. but now I'm having trouble again. I will update the question

Comment: Now your "problem" is that `df[1,2:224] = output2` is only setting values in row 1. 

So what are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to make the first row in the 2nd column pass the 224th containing 'Gen 1'~'Gen 223'